# Ошибка выделения памяти

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, матрицы

Функция в программе предназначена для ввода чисел в матрицу, почему происходит ошибка выделения памяти?

```
#define x 2
#define y 3

void input_matrix(int ** p);

int main()
{
      int a[x][y];
      input_matrix(**a);
      return 0;
}

void input_matrix(int ** p)
{
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
                {
                    printf("p[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                    scanf( "%d", (*(p+i)+j) );
                }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: input_matrix(**a); - это что такое?

Comment: указатель на p[0][0]

Comment: Что значит у Вас **a - какое значение получится и что надо в  input_matrix передать?

Comment: получится адрес самого первого элемента матрицы, прибавляя к которому по единичке можно будет получить адрес всех элементов матрицы и соответственно заполнить их. Или это по-другому работает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637046/how-to-convert-int-to-int-in-c - читайте тут

Comment: `int a[x][y];` - имеет тип матрицы `int [x][y]`, а прога работает с другим типом : указатель на указатель. `int * *` то есть надо матрицу делать для функции того-же типа `int * * a=malloc(...);for(...)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так — `*(p+i)+j` — точно не получится, потому что у вас `p` имеет тип `int**`, так что `p+i` — указатель на `i`-й указатель, а не на `i`-ю строку матрицы.

Надо либо действовать, как описал rusgeli, либо передавать в функцию матрицу

```
void input_matrix(int p[][y]);
```

и тогда ваш код будет работать, либо передавать

```
void input_matrix(int *p);
```

и обращаться к элементу как к

```
*(p+y*i+j)
```

Смотрите сами, какой из трех вариантов вам удобнее.

Comment: *(p+i)+j) - правильно Вы написали, НО берём значение указателя, добавляем смещение - получаем адрес ячейки - Всё работает

Comment: @Виктор Вы в ответе, на который указываете, не поняли главное — там берется прокси-массив! Массив указателей на строки. При `int**` мы имеем массив указателей не на строки, а на указатели! Ну набросайте программку и убедитесь сами. Никогда, никогда, никогда нельзя рассматривать `int**` и `int[][]` как взаимозаменяемые! Разыменование в первом случае дает указатель на `int`, во втором - *на строку* `int`-ов — т.е. на сущность совершенно иного размера.

Comment: Уже набросал с оригинала и проверил. Работает

Comment: Объясните тогда мне, почему вот тут — https://ideone.com/BvRRoj — если раскомментировать строку с вызовом `out2`, программа падает? Я привел исходник, приведите и вы свой, кстати...

Comment: Потому, что надо корректно обращаться к значениям printf("%d  ", *(a+i)+j ); - *(a+i)+j - уже адрес переменной. По поводу кода - я же в ответе написал вроде...

Comment: Хорошо, поясните эти результаты: https://ideone.com/E42KIw :)

Comment: Тип надо корректно приводить out2((int**)&a[0]);

Comment: Хорошо, поясните теперь эти результаты: https://ideone.com/wYQRAU А заодно, чем они отличаются от предыдущих :) Может, хватит уже выдумывать, а стоит просто подумать?

Comment: printf("%d  ", *((a+i*3)+j) ); - смещение на 3 надо ещё

Comment: @Виктор Ага, наконец-то... Заметим, что ничего такого в вашем ответе нет. А вот в моем - есть: `*(p+y*i+j)` — `y` — та самая троечка...

Answer (score 0):

`input_matrix(**a);` -- таким образом вы передаете не указатель, а разыменованное значение, находящееся по адресу элемента `a[0][0]`, поэтому у вас и ошибка. К тому же, при такой работе с массивом, а именно статическим определением и попыткой передать указатель на него, вы получите ошибку несовместимости типов. Вам нужно выделить память динамически через `calloc()` или `malloc()`, а потом уже передавать указатель в функцию `input_matrix()`

Вот пример (`print_matrix()` для демонстрации):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define x 2
#define y 3

void input_matrix(int** p);
void print_matrix(int** p);

int main()
{
    int** a;
    a = (int **) calloc(x, sizeof(int *));     // Выделение памяти под массив
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {              // Выделение памяти под массив
        a[i] = (int *) calloc(y, sizeof(int)); // Выделение памяти под массив 
    }
    
    input_matrix(a);
    print_matrix(a);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // Высвобождение памяти  
        free(a[i]);               // Высвобождение памяти 
    }                             // Высвобождение памяти 
    free(a);                      // Высвобождение памяти 
    return 0;
}

void input_matrix(int ** p) {
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++) {
            printf("p[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf( "%d", (*(p+i)+j) );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_matrix(int ** p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(p + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То есть при работе с указателями на матрицу всегда стоит выделять память под нее динамически?

Comment: @cvetochek Вы так и не прочитали информацию, которую Вам дали - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637046/how-to-convert-int-to-int-in-c

Answer (score -2):

Достаточно привести тип:

```
int a[x][y];
int **ptr = (int**)&a;
input_matrix(ptr);
```